# Create a method that accepts variable length of Function arguments with possibly different types

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

Suppose I have a string: `String s = "1,2,3,4,5,6"`. I would like to create a method `combineFunctions()` that would take a variable length sequence of `Function`s as an argument and apply all of the operations in that order.

The functions may have different `<T,U>` types.

Example uses of such a function would be the following:

```
Combine<String> c = new Combine<>(s);
List<String> numbers = c.combineFunctions(splitByComma);
Integer max = c.combineFunctions(splitByComma,convertToInt, findMax);
```

What I have tried (the `<U>` here is not of much use here):

```
public <U> void combineFunctions(
        Function<? extends Object, ? extends Object>... functions) {

}
```

But I am stuck at getting type of last one of the `Function`s. I was also thinking about a recursive approach but the varargs parameter has to be the last one.

Would it be possible to implement such method in Java?

Comment: what do you mean by this "But I am stuck at getting type of last one of the functions." can you please explain?

Comment: It looks like `Stream` and the `map` method.

Comment: If you know that it will always be called with a relatively small number of arguments (say less than 10 functions) you could write 10 overloaded `combine(Function<T, T1> Function<T1, T2>, ..., Function<Tn, U>)` methods. This is a standard way of keeping type safety while accepting a various (but limited) number of arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with such a function is that you loose all compile-time type checking and casting is necessary.

This would be an implementation, using `andThen` to combine functions together. This looks ugly because of all the casting and I'm not sure you can do it more properly. Notice also that this requires the creation of 2 Stream pipelines when only 1 is really necessary.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
    Function<Object, Object> splitByComma = s -> ((String) s).split(",");
    Function<Object, Object> convertToInt = tokens -> Stream.of((String[]) tokens).map(Integer::valueOf).toArray(Integer[]::new);
    Function<Object, Object> findMax = ints -> Stream.of((Integer[]) ints).max(Integer::compare).get();
    Integer max = (Integer) combineFunctions(splitByComma, convertToInt, findMax).apply(str);
    System.out.println(max);
}

@SafeVarargs
private static Function<Object, Object> combineFunctions(Function<Object, Object>... functions) {
    return Arrays.stream(functions)
                 .reduce(Function::andThen)
                 .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No functions to combine"));
}
```

---

To match the code in your question, you could wrap this into a class like this:

```
public class Combiner<R> {

    private Object input;

    public Combiner(Object input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @SafeVarargs
    public final R combineFunctions(Function<Object, Object>... functions) {
        return (R) Arrays.stream(functions)
                         .reduce(Function::andThen)
                         .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No functions to combine"))
                         .apply(input);
    }

}
```

Comment: I am sorry but it was my mistake - the method doesn't have to be static and I think it is actually impossible to implement a *static* method in a way I have demonstrated in my question (edited the question). Looks like your tips will lead me to the correct solution.

Comment: @REACHUS This is just an sample code. The code of the method can be put inside a class and called in non-static context of course, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks, the code you've added is what I've just come up to myself. Do I understand correctly that in this case there will be only 1 Stream created?

Comment: @REACHUS: it doesn’t matter whether the method is `static` or not. There is no way to support this with type safety using a varargs method. The only way is to use the builder pattern, but that’s exactly what a chain of `map` (on a stream or optional) or repeated `andThen` on the functions invocations already do. If fact, your `Combiner` is almost an `Optional`…

Comment: @REACHUS No, 2 Streams are still created: one in `convertToInt` and one in `findMax`

Comment: @Holger I know that I loose type safety here, I am just exploring boundaries of FP in Java.

Comment: If you accept the lack of type safety, you can implement the `combineFunctions` method just as `Object o=input; for(Function f: functions) o=f.apply(o); return o;` but it’s still unclear why you think you need this…

Answer (score 3):

The example in your question is quite easily solved by using the functional-style [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). The "functional" approach to solving this is by using sequences of `map` operations, each step transforming the elements to a different type, and then optionally reducing/collecting the result.

For instance

```
String str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
int max = Arrays.stream(str.split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).max().orElse(0)
```

The same pattern would apply for other types of "function combinations".