# Variable (Function type) argument count and variable return type

Tags: java, generics, functional-interface

I have the following question- I have to write one method, which will take variable amount of Function arguments and, based on that, will return the needed type. The problem is, that the functions from arguments are run in order:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //Lambda expressions which will be taken as arguments in method.

    Function<String,List<String>> flines = e->{
    };
    Function<List<String>,String> join = e ->{
    };
    Function<String,List<Integer>> collectInts = e->{
    };
    Function<List<Integer>,Integer> sum = e->{
    };

    // end of lambdas

    String fname = System.getProperty("C:/LamComFile.txt"); 
    InputConverter<String> fileConv = new InputConverter<>(fname);
    List<String> lines = fileConv.convertBy(flines);
    String text = fileConv.convertBy(flines, join);
    List<Integer> ints = fileConv.convertBy(flines, join, collectInts);
    Integer sumints = fileConv.convertBy(flines, join, collectInts, sum);

    System.out.println(lines);
    System.out.println(text);
    System.out.println(ints);
    System.out.println(sumints);

    List<String> arglist = Arrays.asList(args);
    InputConverter<List<String>> slistConv = new InputConverter<>(arglist);  
    sumints = slistConv.convertBy(join, collectInts, sum);
    System.out.println(sumints);

    }
}
```

As You can see, I need to create a class, which will have one method (overloading is not allowed) and based on what that method will receive, it has to return the correct type.

I have the beginning of the InputConverter class, but I have no idea how can make the next Functions get the arguments from the ones before.

```
  public class InputConverter<T> {
      private T obj;

      public InputConverter(T obj) {
           this.obj = obj;
      }

      public <what goes here?> and_here convertBy(Function<In,Out>... funcs){

      }
  }
```

I assume that I can do something like this?

```
if(funcs.length()==1){
    what? = funcs[0].apply(this.obj);
    return what?
}
```

Comment: [I](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256485/) [feel a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33298519/) [déjà vu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259637/). Are you all in the same class? That assignment is nonsense.

Comment: There is no way to use varargs to express that the consecutive types must match. You can do `convertBy(Function<?, ?>... funcs)` but then you lose all type safety. I agree that this is a very strange assignment.

Comment: @Holger: Seems like I wasn't the first one on that assignment (1,2 of your hits are correct)- Its half of the college year, the other one will probably get this ridiculous assignment tomorrow. I know that, you know that, almost everyone knows that. Also, the part where you cannot overload the methods was added like few days ago, at the beginning it wasn't there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't express that in Java's type system.  Accept the need for something else.  For example, you could just write `f1.andThen(f2).andThen(f3).andThen(f4)...`.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that I cannot change the Main file, except the lambdas section. Right now I have 4 methods for each example, and it looks (also bad) like this:( public <R,I,O> O convertBy(Function<T,R> flines, Function<R,O> join ...)